# How to select distinct value based on another columns value

Tags: sql, combinations, distinct-values

I have the following data set

| Description | Source |
| --- | --- |
| Phase 1 | Old_value |
| Phase 1 | Old_value |
| Phase 1 | New_value |
| Phase 2 | Old_value |
| Phase 2 | Old_value |
| Phase 2 | Old_value |

I need the find the distinct values and need an output like this

| Description | Source |
| --- | --- |
| Phase 1 | New_value |
| Phase 2 | Old_value |

So based on what is in the source column, I need to find a distinct value in first column (in this case new_value determines where it is grouped/distinct). If there is a new_value, it needs to be the value that it is grouped by, otherwise it needs to group by old_value.
If I only use the distinct function I would get 3 possible combinations like this (Which is not what I want)

| Description | Source |
| --- | --- |
| Phase 1 | Old_value |
| Phase 1 | New_value |
| Phase 2 | Old_value |

Comment: What if 'Phase 2' has 'New_values' too?

Comment: Then it shall also group by the new_value. So if new_value then group by that or else by old_value

Comment: You can't select  distinct values from different columns, because they may have different dimensions. You need to use two different queries

Comment: May be you mean SELECT Source, ANY_VALUE(Description) FROM table GROUP BY Source?

Comment: What if 'Phase 31' has a 'yet_another_value', what if there is a 'Phase 111' ? :) Seriously, your scenario sounds somewhat unusual, at least in an `sql` context, perhaps you could edit your question, and tell everything about the pattern of possible values, and also foresee next-questions about Order By peculiarities perhaps, like the 'x1', x2', 'x11' char sorting problem for example